# CSS3 Transform Opacity Pulsate

Tags: css, opacity, css-transforms

Is there a way to pulsate opacity from 0 to 1 (repeat) slowly with a CSS3 keyframes transformation, infinitely? Or does this require jQuery or Javascript with a transition opacity inside a class that is toggled on an interval?

I'm trying to work it into my orbit transformations (below). (I'm working on a live wallpaper background effect with multiple opaque images floating in a sidebar image on an installer application I'm building in Objective C.)

```
.orbit1
{
animation: myOrbit 200s linear infinite;
}

.orbit2
{
animation: myOrbit2 200s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes myOrbit1 
{
    from { transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(150px) rotate(0deg) }
    to   { transform: rotate(360deg) translateX(150px) rotate(-360deg) }
}

@keyframes myOrbit2 
{
    from { transform: rotate(360deg) translateX(250px) rotate(-360deg) }
    to   { transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(250px) rotate(0deg) }
}
```

Comment: How slowly do you want it to pulsate? The length of the rotation or every 1s or so?

Comment: That's a parameter I can change. I'm probably going to do something subtle like go from 0 to 0.8 within an 8s timeframe.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it by adding multiple animations to the element, for example:

```css
.orbit1
{
  /* added for example reasons */
 position :absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -100px;
  margin-left: -100px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  /* ---------- */
  
  animation: myOrbit1 20s linear infinite, Pulsate 4s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes myOrbit1 
{
    from { transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(150px) rotate(0deg) }
    to   { transform: rotate(360deg) translateX(150px) rotate(-360deg) }
}

@keyframes Pulsate {
  from { opacity: 1; }
  50% { opacity: 0; }
  to { opacity: 1; }
}
```

```html
<div class="orbit1"></div>
```

I'ved modified some of your parameters (like the speed of the animation and the opacity minimum) and added some spoof styling for the element for the purpose of the example.

***Edit***

I had originally thought that the multiple `rotate()` declarations were in error, but @vals informed me [why it was there](http://lea.verou.me/2012/02/moving-an-element-along-a-circle/) (to create a counter rotation on the object). I've updated the answer, and learned something new.

Comment: You comprehended this exactly, and taught me a thing or two about transformations. (I borrowed the code on the rotation transform and am still very green with CSS3.)

Comment: Here's what you helped me achieve -- a small footprint live wallpaper effect in an installer sidebar: http://i.imgur.com/lYxs1lw.gifv

Comment: @Volomike wow, that's awesome! Amazing what a little animation adds. I'm glad I could help. :)

Comment: Warning ! the transform was probably correct, and the sugestion that you are making is not... it is correct that the rotate is doubled !

Comment: @vals ok, I'll bite. Why would it be correct to have the rotate attribute twice in the same declaration? I cannot find anything to suggest it, and it broke the animation.

Comment: Check this article http://lea.verou.me/2012/02/moving-an-element-along-a-circle/ from Lea Verou, and inside it, the demo from the idea of  Aryeh Gregor

Comment: @vals I stand mistaken, thanks for sharing that! I'll update the answer with the correction.

Comment: I agree it's a strange construction... It also surprised me when I saw it :-)

Comment: Each version has its merits. In my case, the version without the second `rotate()` call caused the image to seem more alive in [my demo gif movie of it](http://i.imgur.com/lYxs1lw.gifv).